# Postgresql version for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently running ubuntu version 14.04 (trusty)

I know there's no longer support for this version. However, I want to know what's the highest version of postgresql that I can install for this version (14.04).

Comment: What happened when you tried installing a current version e.g. 14? You probably need to compile it yourself though.

Comment: i'm on version 9.4 but want to upgrade as high as possible

Comment: _what's the highest version of postgresql that I can install_ -- this obviously depends on _how_ you want to install it.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is pretty tolerant of old versions of required software, you you can get the source code of the latest version and [install PostgreSQL from the source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/installation.html). Make sure you meet the [requirements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-requirements.html) and install or upgrade software as necessary.

One warning: people who continue to use old software also tend to use old hardware. The first makes you vulnerable to security leaks, and the latter is the prime cause for data corruption.